# Is there any virtual MIDI loopback solution for Ubuntu/Linux?

Tags: sound, music, midi

I'm not sure how many of you play music, but in Windows there are several virtual MIDI loopback software to route MIDI from one program to another. For example, [loopMIDI](http://www.tobias-erichsen.de/software/loopmidi.html) and [midiyoke](http://www.midiox.com/myoke.htm), and [LoopBe1](http://www.nerds.de/en/loopbe1.html). In Mac, I think it is known as IAC drivers.

Is there any virtual MIDI loopback solution for Ubuntu/Linux?

These are my available devices as shown by a Java applet,

```
Available MIDI Devices:
----------Input----------
[0] "Real Time Sequencer"
----------Output----------
[0] "Gervill"
[1] "Real Time Sequencer"
```

Answer (score 1):

In Linux, applications can create the same kind of MIDI port as drivers, so a MIDI loopback driver is typically not necessary.

If you want to use one anyway, you can use the "Midi Through" port(s) created by the `snd-seq-dummy` driver, which is loaded automatically.

Comment: I'm using a Java application which only shows me "Real time Sequencer" and "Gervill" output

Comment: Sun's JVM thinks it is a good idea to bypass the ALSA sequencer and access the hardware directly, but you can use the `snd-virmidi` driver for that.

Comment: Thanks! I've enabled it with `sudo modprobe snd-virmidi` and printed like 35 virtual midi devices. Any way to reduce them?

Comment: You get 16 entries per port; `midi_devs=1` will not help much.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the program which you are looking for is Jack, which cann be used to route midi data from one program to another.

Jack can be fairly complicated to setup, and a good tutorial can be found at https://libremusicproduction.com/articles/demystifying-jack-%E2%80%93-beginners-guide-getting-started-jack

The basics would be to install jack, which can be most easily accomplished by installing one of the jack management tools to start Jack, and to create routes.

`sudo apt install qjackctl`

will do this for you.